# How to create custom buttons with clickable area defined by coordinates ? (Ionic)

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to build an application where you need to click on a body composed by muscles like this one : 
[image].

I don't know if it's possible to click on each muscles with a shape defined by coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to set an event on parts of the image using coordinates.
Just look into this live ionic project developed by @Crackroach

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-dqzfse

Note: solar-system image takes little time to load